# Phoenix.NotAcceptableError: no supported media type in accept header

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, mime-types, mime

When I run my Phoenix framework tests, I got this error:

```
** (Phoenix.NotAcceptableError) no supported media type in accept header.

Expected one of ["html"] but got the following formats:

  * "application/json" with extensions: ["json"]

To accept custom formats, register them under the :mime library
in your config/config.exs file:

    config :mime, :types, %{
      "application/xml" => ["xml"]
    }

And then run `mix deps.clean --build mime` to force it to be recompiled.
```

Even when I add this line to my `config.exs` I still get the errors:

```
config :mime, :types, %{
  "application/json" => ["json"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `plug :accepts, ["json"]` somewhere in a router pipeline? (see [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.NotAcceptableError.html))

Comment: That's it! I put the route in the :browser scope, I should change it to :api to accept json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your `router.ex` file, you'll have something like this that defines pipelines for your routes to use:

```
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_live_flash
    plug :put_root_layout, {FirehoseWeb.LayoutView, :root}
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end
```

Then further down, you'll have scopes that use those pipelines and define routes:

```
  scope "/", AppWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end
```

The scope above is piped through `:browser`, so it only accepts html. If you have separate route "/api/foo" that's JSON-only, then you'll want to define another scope for it pipes through `:api` like this:

```
    scope "/api", AppWeb do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/foo", FooController
  end
```

If you want the same route to handle both HTML and JSON, then, change the first plug in your pipeline to: `plug :accepts, ["html", "json"]`